# Mocking private method with Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to find an article about mocking private methods. Actually we use mockito in our project, but it is so poor test coverage. So I tried to write with Mockito and PowerMock butI cann't find any good examples and so on. Can anybody explain me this?

Comment: Why do you want to mock private methods? This is usually a bad idea.

Comment: If you think you need to mock a private method, that means you're changing the behaviour of the public method that you're trying to test.  Therefore, it's very likely that you're not writing a valid test.  Can you post some more details of what you're actually trying to achieve, and maybe someone can give you some more targetted help or advice about what should be in your tests.  But mocking private methods is seldom part of a good test for a class; which is why Mockito doesn't provide this functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a job for PowerMock.  I doubt Mockito can do it.  [The PowerMock documentation explains how to do it.](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockPrivate)  And, it uses this as an example:

```
@Test
public void testReplaceData() throws Exception {
        final String modifyDataMethodName = "modifyData";
        final byte[] expectedBinaryData = new byte[] { 42 };
        final String expectedDataId = "id";

        // Mock only the modifyData method
        DataService tested = createPartialMock(DataService.class, modifyDataMethodName);

        // Expect the private method call to "modifyData"
        expectPrivate(tested, modifyDataMethodName, expectedDataId,
                        expectedBinaryData).andReturn(true);

        replay(tested);

        assertTrue(tested.replaceData(expectedDataId, expectedBinaryData));

        verify(tested);
}
```