# Is a stub required to unit test try-catch block?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have some code that contains a try-catch block. Upon checking my code coverage, I noticed that my catch block isn't covered.

```
public bool TryDoSomething()
{
    try
    {
        SomePrivateMethod();
      
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // some logs

        return false;
    }
}
```

I know that, using a stub, I can easily make it throw for me, thus entering the catch block.
But what if the code is self contained like the example above?

Do I *have to* somehow extract the code just to make it throw? Like this

```
public bool TryDoSomething()
{
    try
    {
        _someDependencyInjectedEarlier.SomeMethod();
      
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // some logs

        return false;
    }
}
```

Or the other way around (feels odd):

```
public bool TryDoSomething()
{
    return _injectedHelper.Try<Exception>(
        () => SomePrivateMethods(),
        e => { /* some logs */ }
    );
}
```

with `Try` being

```
    public bool Try<T>(Action action, Action<T> onError) where T: Exception
    {
        try
        {
            action();
            return true;
        }
        catch (T e)
        {
            onError(e);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Or maybe some IL generated at runtime to make it throw? Which seems very complicated and wrong as well.

What are my options?
Should I be posting this on another sub instead?

Comment: What does `SomePrivateMethod()` do?  What dependencies on the object does it use which can be mocked, or what inputs can be provided to the object?  Presumably there's *something* environmental somewhere which can result in an exception, otherwise the try/catch is superfluous anyway.

Comment: @David Yes but my goal is to not have to mock whatever goes on inside the try block and only assert and test what goes on if/when it fails, that it is properly caught and how it behaves in the catch block.

Comment: Is this a fair expectation to want to test that? Is this bad smell? Do I need to rethink the problem or the solution differently?

Comment: It's not a question of mocking "what's in the try block" or mocking "methods", it's a question of mocking dependencies of the object as a whole.  Presumably the functionality being tested on this object has (1) inputs and/or (2) dependencies.  Those are what the unit test provides.  For example, if the method just does `return 1 + 1;` then there are no inputs or dependencies, and there's no need for exception handling in the first place.  But if the method does `_someService.SomeOperation();` then `_someService` is a dependency to be mocked.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use mocking frameworks like Mockito to write unit tests.  Here is an example from 2013 using Mockito with PowerMock.

[Mocking private method with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149002/mocking-private-method-with-mockito)

With a mocking framework, you intercept calls to real methods and provide mocked responses without actually executing the called methods.  In this case, since you want to trigger an exception, you need to have Mockito intercept the call and throw an exception.

Here is example Mockito code to do that:

```
doThrow(new Exception()).when(mockedObject).SomePrivateMethod(...);
```

You may want your original code to be restructured to make mocking that called method easier.

Answer (score 1):

When writing unit tests for your objects, don't think of mocks in terms of "methods" or "try blocks".  Think of mocks in terms of two things:

- Inputs
- Dependencies

The unit test provides those two things, in the form of directly inputting values and mocking dependencies.

So the question isn't:

> How can I get this *method call* to fail?

But rather:

> What *input* or *dependency* can cause this functionality to fail?

As a contrived example, imagine the method being invoked does this:

```
return 1 + 1;
```

There are no inputs, no dependencies.  All of the logic is fully enclosed within the object being tested.  And that logic *can't fail*.  So there's no need for a `try/catch` in the first place and the solution is to remove that structure.

Or, suppose the method being invoked does this:

```
return 1 / this.x;
```

Where does `this.x` come from?  That's potentially an input.  For example, maybe it's supplied to the constructor when creating the object.  In this case, if you were to supply `0` to the constructor, you'd trigger an exception.  The unit test should supply `0` and validate the result.

Or, suppose the method being invoked does this:

```
return this._someService.SomeOperation();
```

What is `_someService`?  Is that another object on which this object depends?  Then that's a dependency to be mocked.  If it's being internally constructed:

```
this._someService = new SomeService();
```

Then now is the time to "invert the dependency" and make it a constructor parameter instead of internally creating it.  If it's already a constructor parameter, that's how the unit test would provide a mock.

---

Overall the point is that the unit test isn't testing *implementation* (it doesn't care what/where the `try/catch` structure it, it doesn't care what private methods are invoked, etc.), it's testing *functionality*.  And the object should advertise the inputs/dependencies it needs to perform that functionality.

If there are no inputs or dependencies then the logic shouldn't be able to fail, because such failure potential would literally be *hard-coded* into the logic itself.  You can manually test it during development to harden it against failures.  But if there *are* inputs and/or dependencies, those can provide a situation in which the logic being tested could potentially fail.  Those should be mocked for tests.

Comment: Well, the try-catch was also there to be future-proof. Whatever changes someone may happen in the future, it should still try & catch. Currently, it might be useless and thus should go but then, what if someone makes an innocuous change that now _may_ fail. Is it _their_ responsibility to re-add the try-catch? Do we have a safer way to handle this? Maybe if this should never fail, this should be tested on the caller level.

Comment: @jeromej: *"what if someone makes an innocuous change that now may fail. Is it their responsibility to re-add the try-catch?"* - Absolutely.  And it may not even be in the same place, or catch the same type of exception, or handle it the same way.  When someone modifies the functionality in such a way that dependencies are introduced which carry potential failure scenarios, that programmer needs to account for those scenarios.  There's no way to completely future-proof the code, and no way to meaningfully test failure scenarios that can't currently happen.